# How do you sort a String List by the number of words matched with an Array in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to sort a String List by the number of words matched from a string array?

```
var targets = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("one little pony");
    list.Add("one two little pony");
    list.Add("one two three little pony");
    list.Add("little pony");
x = x.OrderByDescending(u => targets.Any(u.Contains)).ToList();
foreach(var item in list)
{
 Debug.Writeline(item);
}
```

Is there a way to generate an output **without using another `list` or `for` loop to sort**

```
one two three little pony
one two little pony
one little pony
little pony
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Count` instead of `Any`:

```
x = x.OrderByDescending(u => targets.Count(u.Contains)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Stanley. I had made a mistake in the code I originally submitted. I have edited the code. Please edit your answer from `u.Tags.Contains` to `u.Contains` to make it more relevant to the edited code.

Answer (score 3):

Another   approach which sorts the original list with [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of creating a new one:

```
var targets = new HashSet<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
list.Sort((s1, s2) => -1 * (s1.Split().Count(targets.Contains)
                 .CompareTo(s2.Split().Count(targets.Contains))));
```

`-1 *` is used to sort descending, so the most occurrences on top. This also splits by white-space insetad of searching sub-strings since you've mentioned that you want to count *words*.

I've used a `HashSet<string>` since it's more efficient for lookups and duplicates should not be counted more than once  anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = list.OrderByDescending(phrase => 
    phrase.Split().Intersect(targets).Count());
```

What you're conceptually doing here is looking at the count of the intersection of the two sets of words.  The intersection is the set of items that exist in both of two other sets.